# how to use persistence type="dynamic" in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to use a dynamic persistence type in an attribute but when I update the systems it appears like jalo type.

```
<attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="productCode" type="java.lang.String" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
  <persistence type="dynamic"/>
  <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="false" initial="false" optional="true"/>
  <custom-properties>
    <property name="param">
      <value>Boolean.FALSE</value>
    </property>
    <property name="position">
      <value>Integer.valueOf(1)</value>
    </property>
  </custom-properties>
</attribute>
```

But, when I check in XML representation in backoffice it is represented in this way:

```
<attribute generate="true" autocreate="true" qualifier="productCode" type="java.lang.String" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
  <persistence type="jalo" qualifier=""/>
  <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="false" encrypted="false" optional="true" removable="true" initial="false" unique="false" private="false" partof="false"/>
  <custom-properties>
    <property name="param">
      <value>Boolean.FALSE</value>
    </property>
    <property name="position">
      <value>new Integer(1)</value>
    </property>
  </custom-properties>
</attribute>
```

I change this property to false: `persistence.legacy.mode=false`

I don't know why if it's declared as dynamic latter it is changed to jalo. can someone explain me.

Comment: Since you ask, I just check in backoffice of some itemtype that have dynamic attribute, and it also shows jalo. You can check "statusDisplay" attribute in Order for OOTB so I think it's normal behaviour, I don't know why though so I just left a comment here.

Comment: Did you tried adding a attributeHandler to the dynamic attribute
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/8bb46096866910149208fae7c4ec7596.html

Answer (score 0):

When using attribute type dynamic, you have to provide a bean to handle the attribute value. Like this:

```
<persistence type="dynamic" attributeHandler="someBean" />
```

source: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/8bb46096866910149208fae7c4ec7596.html

Comment: But it also says if you don't declare a handler it will be created automatically. and actually, it is made, but the XML representation continued with dynamic: "For each Dynamic Attribute, a Spring bean ID known as attributeHandler is automatically generated. However, you may provide the custom bean ID. The naming convention of the automatically generated attributeHandler object is: <ItemtypeCode>_<attributeQualifier>AttributeHandler"